# How to detect beacons using Android Beacon Library in foreground and background?

Tags: android, xamarin, beacon

I am trying to detect beacons while my app is running and put them in a list and also detect when not running and display a notification.  I can't seem to get both working at the same time on android.

I have my main activity...

```
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IMonitorNotifier, IRangeNotifier, IBeaconConsumer, IBootstrapNotifier

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    set beacon parsers
    beaconmanager.bind(this)
    ...

public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
{
    BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.RemoveAllMonitorNotifiers();
    BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.RemoveAllRangeNotifiers();

    BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.AddMonitorNotifier(this);
    BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.AddRangeNotifier(this);

    StartMonitoringBeacons...
    StartRangingBeacons...
}
```

Then I have a separate class...

```
[Activity(LaunchMode=LaunchMode.SingleInstance, Label="MyApp", MainLauncher = true)]
public class LaunchApplication : Application, IBootstrapNotifier, IRangeNotifier, IBeaconConsumer
{
    private RegionBootstrap _bootstrap = null;

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        var proximities = BeaconManager.Instance.GetServerProximitiesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var regions = proximities.Select(x => new Region(x.UUID, null, null, null)).ToList();

        BeaconManager.GetParsers().ForEach(x => BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(x));

        _bootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, regions);
    }
    public void DidEnterRegion(Region region)
    {
        add parsers
        beaconmanager.bind(this);
    }
    public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
        BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.AddMonitorNotifier(this);
        BeaconManager.AndroidBeaconManager.AddRangeNotifier(this);

        start monitoring...
        start ranging...
```

I don't add anything to my manifest because I believe it does automatically with the Activity attribute.

My question is am I supposed to have a MainActivity and a separate class that derives from Application (that creates a region bootstrap)?

do I bind to different instances (bind(this))?

When I debug the LaunchApplication OnCreate never gets called so how does it ever create a region bootstrap?

how am I supposed to set this up to just detect while running in foreground and background?

Thanks.

Comment: What Xamarin library are you using for this?    Does it have examples on how to set up RegionBootstrap?  I am the lead dev of the Android Beacon Library, and know how it works with native apps, but I am not sure how the Xamarin library wrapper changes this.  You clearly *Must* get onCreate to be called somelhow.  We need a Xamarin expert to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help david.  The problem is I see no way for an app to scan for beacons in the foreground AND scan them when not running.  Once you call RegionBootstrap it gets rid of the existing monitors and rangers.  Have you ever written an app that does both without Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific issue, you do not need to call bind() in the activity -- it has already been done internally by RegionBootstrap (so long as you can confirm that onCreate is called in the custom application class).

To make this work both places, you simply need to remove the call to bind() and take out the code that removes the ranging and monitoring regions in the activity (if you remove all monitor notifiers, you effectively disable RegionBootstrap callbacks because you are removing its notifier).   Just leave the code in your activity that adds new monitor and range notifiers for that activity and start ranging and monitoring as desired for the activity.

Keep mind that BeaconManager is a singleton.  You have one set of ranged and monitored regions for all components of your app (both the application and activity class instance).  Because of this, you only need to bind once (constructing and you can add as many notifiers as you like.  If you remove notifiers in one class it will remove them from the other classes as well.

Comment: David...I verified that if I use the BackgroundPowerSaver(this); then it works.  Without it I do not receive any events in the foreground while running and also using RegionBootstrap.  do u know a reason for this?  I have everything in the main activity now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your problem, but could be a starting point:

https://github.com/acaliaro/AltBeaconLibrarySample

this is the "java binding" to @davidgyoung library

https://github.com/acaliaro/BeaconLibraryBindings

You can also find something here : https://github.com/chrisriesgo/Android-AltBeacon-Library